# Get XML layout inside another XML layout by code [Android]

Tags: android, xml, view

I have one xml file main_layout.xml and in this I have another xml layout popup_layout.xml which is added by :

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    layout="@layout/popup_layout" />
```

In the file MainActivity.java I would like to get the popup object so I can change it's textfields etc. What do i write?

I've tested

```
        View v = findViewById(R.id.popup);
    TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ip_answer);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: what's the content of the popup_layout.xml file?

Comment: maybe instead of using the include, you could use a separate XML file and a layoutInflater?

Comment: It's an RelativeLayout with some TextViews and a button, nothing complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id attribute for include is not required. Add id attribute to the layout you want to include , then find view by that id an collect it accordingly as the type of layout
eg:

```
RelativeLayout/LinearLayout= findViewById(id);
```

then find the text view .
This should work